# Regex to replace character with character itself and hyphen

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to replace some camelCase characters with the camel Case character and a `-`.

What I have got is a string like those:

```
Albert-Weisgerber-Allee 35
Bruninieku iela 50-10
```

Those strings are going through this regex to seperate the number from the street:

```
$data = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", '', $data);
$pcre = '\A\s*(.*?)\s*\x2f?(\pN+\s*[a-zA-Z]?(?:\s*[-\x2f\pP]\s*\pN+\s*[a-zA-Z]?)*)\s*\z/ux';
preg_match($pcre, $data, $h);
```

Now, I have two problems.

1. I'm very bad at regex.
2. Above regex also cuts every `-` from the streets name, and there are a lot of those names in germany and europe.

Actually it would be quite easy to just adjust the regex to not cut any hyphens, but I want to learn how regex works and so I decided to try to find a regex that just replaces every camel case letter in the string with

```
- & matched Camel Case letter
```

except for the first uppercase letter appearance.

I've managed to find a regex that shows me the places I need to paste a hyphen like so:

```
.[A-Z]{1}/ug
```

https://regex101.com/r/qI2iA9/1

But how on earth do I replace this string:

```
AlbertWeisgerberAllee
```

that it becomes

```
Albert-Weisgerber-Allee
```

Comment: So, all you need to do is put a hyphen before uppercase letters, right?

Comment: Yes, only except the first one @Anonymous

Comment: instead of fixing the output of one faulty regex with an other regex, i recommend you to just fix the first regex (it is possible) to not replace the `-`s before the numbers. just rewrite the whole regex from scratch. if you did not yet do that, follow a (lengthy) regex tutorial, and give yourself a whole day or more time to just learn regex (forgetting about your problem for this time). it will make your coding life so much less frustrating whenever you need regex.

Comment: @hoijui Totally agree, did exactly what you have just recommended the week before last week. And you are so right, knowing how regex works is worth so much...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To insert dashes before caps use this regex:

```
$string="AlbertWeisgerberAllee";
$string=preg_replace("/([a-z])([A-Z])/", "\\1-\\2", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use capture groups:

```
(.)([A-Z])        //removed {1} because [A-Z] implicitly matches {1}
```

And replace with `$1-$2`

See https://regex101.com/r/qI2iA9/3

Comment: This doesn't match `AlbertWWeisgerberAllee` correctly.

Comment: @Anonymous thats not `CamelCase`... so no worries.. also that should become `Albert-WWeisgerber-Allee` which is what my regex does  :)

Comment: According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/camel%20case), camel case is "the convention of writing compound words or phrases with no spaces and an initial lowercase or uppercase letter, with each remaining word element beginning with an uppercase letter". However, it is ultimately up to the OP which they meant to ask about. :)

Comment: In this case it's like @karthikmanchala said, the CamelCase I've been after was the one his regex matches

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be over complicating the expression. You can use the following to place `-` before any uppercase letters except the first:

```
(.)(?=[A-Z])
```

Just replace that with `$1-`. Essentially, what this regex does is:

1. `(.)` Find any character and place that character in group 1.
2. `(?=[A-Z])` See if an uppercase character follows.
3. `$1-` If matched, replace with the character found in group 1 followed by a hyphen.